# Can a capacitor be briefly charged above its voltage rating?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, supercapacitor

Lets assume I have a supercapacitor rated for 5v at 200F. That's 2500 joules of energy. My wall socket outputs 120V at a maximum of 15A, which is 1800 watts (or joules per second). If I hook up my capacitor to 120V DC at 15 amps for 1 second, I would expect my capacitor to be charged up to 1800 joules, or about 4.2 volts.

My expectation is that since the voltage across the capacitor is never above 5v, it should be fine.

Will this work in practice, or would my capacitor blow up in my face if I tried this? And if not, why?

Comment: Before you try: This will not work. *boom*. :) I don't have time to explain why, but someone will. (Hint: A 15 A fuse isn't really limiting the current.)

Comment: @pipe I meant to include that the current would be limited to 15 amps. I don't mean literally shoving the cap terminals into the wall :P The circuit would be something like [AC-DC rectifier -> 8 ohm resister -> supercap]

Comment: What you really want is a constant current supply.

Comment: @MattYoung That would be **much** better. Though my question is more about how capacitors work, rather than asking if this is a good idea or not.

Comment: Also, as a side note, just directly rectifying 120VAC results in nominally 170VDC, not 120VDC.

Comment: The answer in the detailed scenario you give is : no, but the scenario works because you're not charging it above its voltage rating. With 4V across the cap, the other 116V (or 166V) is dropped across the current limiter (big resistor, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw out your circuit and do the analysis.

Assuming you mean 120VAC -> rectifier -> resistor -> supercap, and you've got magic hands to unplug the cap when it reaches a certain voltage, it's theoretically possible- the voltage rating of the cap only "cares" about the actual voltage across the cap, and in this case the line voltage is across both the cap and the resistor. However, it's a horrible idea. Please don't hurt yourself.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks :) And no, I don't plan to try this. It's a terrible idea. This exact scenario was theoretical just to get my question across.

Comment: If you don't remove the capacitor from the circuit, it's voltage would eventually rise to the rectified voltage being charged through the resistor though, right? And once that voltage rises above the rating of the capacitor, material science and chemistry kicks in and things take a turn for the worse before you get anywhere near that full scale rectified voltage. The fundamental governing principle of a capacitor with capacitance C is that Q = C * V, which is to say given a certain voltage across its plates, and knowing its capacitance, you can infer the accumulated charge on its plates.

Comment: @vicatcu correct. Some time into charging you violate the rating, and some time after that your capacitor vents. Here is a video of what happens. Supercaps are a bit different from what he used, but it'll be similar enough. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3b7mjukhTyQ

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question, as though you were plugging into a 120VAC socket:

The supercapacitor would do one of two things, depending on the AC phase at which you close the circuit, and the initial charge on the supercapacitor.

1. If the supercapacitor is not *sufficiently* charged and the circuit closes
   during any phase but the zero crossing of the AC into the correct
   polarity of the supercapacitor, the reverse polarity phase of the AC
   would completely discharge the supercapacitor and enter into a
   reverse polarity.  As a result, the supercapacitor would likely blow
   or be damaged, as in [this video](https://youtu.be/4yZxNKyd_lM?t=147).  This would likely happen
   faster than the facility's circuit breakers could react due to the
   extremely low ESR (internal resistance) of the supercapacitor.
2. If the capacitor is *partially* charged, or if it is not charged but the circuit
   closes at the zero crossing into the forward polarity phase of the
   AC, the supercapacitor would not be damaged before the facility's circuit
   breakers open the circuit in response to the huge currents going
   into and out of the supercapacitor.  I say *partially* because the supercapacitor could not dis/charge 100F in 1/120 of a second despite the ridiculously small ESR because the facility's wiring would impart limiting resistance sufficient to avoid over (or reverse) charging.